# Referring the image with bibliography

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I am trying to refer to figure number with its reference like below...
can anyone help me with this?

```
Figure                   … as illustrated in [5, Fig. 1]

Table                     … is presented in [5, Tab. 3]

Equation              … as seen in [5, eq. (2)]
```

for more to see check out this link https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/figurestablesequations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misinterpreting what you want, but it appears that what you want is as simple as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

See \cite[Figure~1]{Einstein:1905ve}, 
see \cite[page~11]{Einstein:1905cc},
see \cite[Equation~(2)]{Einstein:1912bi}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{Einstein:1905ve}
A.~Einstein,
\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies},
Annalen Phys.\ \textbf{17}, 891-921 (1905)

\bibitem{Einstein:1905cc}
A.~Einstein,
\textit{Concerning an heuristic point of view toward the emission and
transformation of light},
Annalen Phys.\ \textbf{17}, 132-148 (1905)

\bibitem{Einstein:1912bi}
A.~Einstein,
\textit{The Speed of Light and the Statics of the Gravitational Field},
Annalen Phys.\ \textbf{38}, 355-369 (1912)
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... This is excatly i needed... For my report I have just added the reference of the figure like below. 

\cite[Figure \ref{fig:structure}]{Einstein:1905ve}